# Query execution failed for dataset. Server: The operation has been cancelled

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, ssrs-2008, cube

An error has occurred during local report processing.

An error has occured during report processing.

Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet_XXXXX'

Server: The operation has been cancelled.

What the William H Gates is going on here?

I am trying to preview a report, that uses datasets which connect to ssas cubes, in the report designer.

I'm using SSRS2008 on xpsp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the query to use a different dimension containing the same data and it works.

The number of dimensions used in the query was reduced from 3 to 2.

I guess by touching the other dimension it was creating a large dataset which in turn caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull the report apart and run each query manually to find the failure.

Comment: But a dataset only uses one query, so I know which query it is.

Comment: Then run that query outside the report. Try to replicate the same security context if you can. If you can't & the query succeeds then you know the problem is security related. If the query fails then you should get a meaningful error. What you have posted is too generic to diagnose.

Comment: It's not security related. It is one particular query that is causing this. Am trying to ascertain what might be different about this particular query.